# Different workers for different queues

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to configure my celery so I have separate workers for separate queues. But at the end it appears that all queues use
This is my config for queues and workers.
`CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300000000 -c 192  -c:modBFS 64 -Q:modBFS bfs -c:evaluateWiFi 64 -Q wifi -c:checkNode 64 -Q node"`

When I run celery -A run.celery inspect registered I get this

```
-> checkNode@demeter: OK
* CheckWiFi.evaluateWiFi
* modBFS.checkNode
* modBFS.modBFS
-> modBFS@demeter: OK
* CheckWiFi.evaluateWiFi
* modBFS.checkNode
* modBFS.modBFS
-> evaluateWiFi@demeter: OK
* CheckWiFi.evaluateWiFi
* modBFS.checkNode
* modBFS.modBFS
```

my terminal output when I restart celery services is

```
celery init v10.1.
Using config script: /etc/default/celeryd
celery multi v4.1.0 (latentcall)
> Stopping nodes...
> checkNode@demeter: TERM -> 15729
> evaluateWiFi@demeter: TERM -> 15763
> modBFS@demeter: TERM -> 15831
> Waiting for 3 nodes -> 15729, 15763, 15831.......
> checkNode@demeter: OK
> Restarting node checkNode@demeter: OK
> Waiting for 3 nodes -> None, None, None....
> evaluateWiFi@demeter: OK
> Restarting node evaluateWiFi@demeter: OK
> Waiting for 2 nodes -> None, None....
> modBFS@demeter: OK
> Restarting node modBFS@demeter: OK
> Waiting for 1 node -> None...
```

So what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: did you set up the queues in the celery config before defining the opts?

Comment: @Jason  you mean these lines?
app.config['CELERY_ROUTES'] = {
    'celery.tasks.modBFS.modBFS': {'queue': 'bfs'},
    'celery.tasks.modBFS.checkNode': {'queue': 'node'},
    'celery.tasks.CheckWiFi.evaluateWiFi':{'queue':'wifi'}
}

Comment: ok, you have that set.  how about the celery startup.  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2257119/29490073-338d1ef4-84e6-11e7-8ae1-717d1d535474.png do you have any output along the Queues line?

Comment: @Jason I am running celery as daemon.  Are there anyway I can see those lines when I am running celery as daemon?

Comment: theyll be part of the celery startup output in the terminal when you do `sudo service celeryd start` or your other equivalent

Comment: @Jason when I start celery I only get those lines
`celery init v10.1.
Using config script: /etc/default/celeryd
celery multi v4.1.0 (latentcall)
> Starting nodes...
<class 'celery.app.task.Task'>
> modBFS@demeter: OK
<class 'celery.app.task.Task'>
> checkNode@demeter: OK
<class 'celery.app.task.Task'>
> evaluateWiFi@demeter: OK`

Comment: would help if you updated your question with the terminal output when you start the service.